# Нужен ли новый сайт в лесу AD?

Tags: сеть, администрирование, lan, active-directory

у меня сейчас сеть с 2мя ДК территориально разнесёнными
в офисе сеть 204.85.134.0/24
в филиале 10.10.4.0/24
[image: Текущая сеть]

Контора переезжает, и отказывается от временного филиала (где сейчас располагается второй ДК)
Во время переезда у нас будет 2 ДК но второй уже не с филиала - а новый.
В новом офис сеть: 10.0.0.0/23
[image: Переезд]

После переезда старый контроллер будет убран. Но добавится новый "железный" ДК.
[image: Итоговая сеть]

и меня интересует необходимо ли создавать новый сайт для нового офиса?

Дело в том что я решил предварительно почитать статьи по моей теме, и нашёл вот такую фразу:

> Прежде чем добавлять новый сервер в домен и устанавливать на нём роль
>   AD DS необходимо создать новый сайт (только для филиалов, в пределах
>   одной локальной сети сайт создавать не нужно!) и определить сеть для
>   него. Сайт (site) - одна или несколько сетей TCP\IP имеющих
>   высокоскоростное соединение. Как правило, сайты являются географически
>   распределёнными. При наличии современных подключений к интернету,
>   например FTTX, и небольших объёмах репликации необходимость нескольких
>   сайтов может не понадобиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получил ответ на тостере:

> у вас все в одном месте и сайт вам не нужен , втрой КД можно и нужно иметь , все будет ок [@oia](https://toster.ru/answer?answer_id=586826)

Воспользовался им - и действительно никакой проблемы для работы AD отсутствие разделения на сайты не создаёт. А учитывая что разделение временное, два раза вмешиваться в структуру леса не стоит.